# VueJS2 Atualização de Diretivas

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Estou com um problema na minha diretiva de Dinheiro, ela funciona assim: Eu faço uma chamada Axios para minha API, a API me traz um valor e eu formato para o padrão BR.
Mas agora tive que criar um botão de `atualizar`que está me trazendo este problema de formatação. Alguém sabe fazer isso funcionar por favor?

> É esperado que quando clicar no botão `getNewValue`, o valor `test` seja atualizado e formatado corretamente

JSFiddle: [AQUI](http://jsfiddle.net/ekgkrgko/16/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
<span v-money>{{test}}</span>
<button @click="getNewValue()">Get New Value</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    const formatNumber = (el) => {

   let valorFinal = el.innerHTML;

   if(valorFinal.includes(',')) valorFinal = valorFinal.replace(/\./g, "").replace(',','.'); 

   el.innerHTML = parseFloat(valorFinal).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2});
};

Vue.directive('money', {
   inserted: function (el) {
      let waitingAPI = setInterval(function () {
         if (el.innerHTML != null && el.innerHTML != '') {
            clearInterval(waitingAPI);
            formatNumber(el);
         }
      }, 300);
   },
   update(el){
       formatNumber(el);
   }
})

const demo = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data:{
    test: 10.25
  },
  methods:{
    getNewValue(){
      setTimeout( () => {
        alert('Response Success API!')
        this.test = 1300.25
      },1000)
    }
  }

});
```

Obrigado desde já :)

Comment: Uma dúvida, necessariamente deve ser um span com a diretiva v-money? Ou poderia ser um input? Não tenho exata certeza que entendo o problema, mas creio que alterando resolveria, também posso tentar explicar o que eu acho que está acontecendo entre o resultado esperado e o que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Necessariamente deve ser span com diretiva v-money, exatamente como está no código. Nesse caso isso seria uma tela de Detalhes do preço. Não é um input. Pelo que vi o que está acontecendo é que após eu dar o innerHTML, aparentemente ele perde a reatividade... Esse botão de `getNewValue` seria uma simulação de um **get** na API trazendo um novo valor do banco para aquele preço. Não sei como resolver isso ( a formatação ) =/

Comment: Não seria mais apropriado utilizar um filtro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente setar o valor à ser formatado como valor da diretiva.

```js
var intl = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })
Vue.directive('money', {
  bind: function (el, binding) {
    el.innerHTML = intl.format(binding.value)
  },
  update: function (el, binding) {
    el.innerHTML = intl.format(binding.value)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      valor: 10.25
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>
    Valor:
    <input type="text" v-model="valor" />
  </label>
  <span v-money="valor"></span>
</div>
```

porém, me baseando pelo seu exemplo, acredito que um filtro seja mais apropriado

```js
var intl = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })
Vue.filter('money', function (value) {
  return intl.format(value)
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      valor: 10.25
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>
    Valor:
    <input type="text" v-model="valor" />
  </label>
  <span>{{valor | money}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito cara! Era exatamente isso que eu estava buscando!! Muito obrigado!!